# Is there an equivalent of Excel's PERCENTRANK (column,value) in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there an equivalent of Excel's PERCENTRANK (column,value) in SQL? I think native SQL Server functions provide only percentiles from the same column, but am I missing something?

The problem is that I have two columns - A and B - and I need to use distribution of values from column A and then take values from another column and rank them against column A - how do values in B fit in distribution defined by column A (or, precisely: get CDF of column A at point defined by B).

Possible solutions:

1. Write UDF (they don't parallelize, do they?) - can you answer how could I efficiently structure such UDF?
2. Use SQL Server 2016 and integrate it with R (R code within SQL code)
3. Copy data to R, perform calculations, send back to server
4. Copy data to Excel and calculate it over there "manually", import results back to database

There are multiple columns with values and distributions I need to apply this strategy to, so I am looking for an efficient solution.

Edit - example:
    `column A    column B    result 
    10          16          0,20     =PERCENTRANK($A1:$A4, B1)
    20          35          0,83     =PERCENTRANK($A1:$A4, B2)
    30          10          0,00     =PERCENTRANK($A1:$A4, B3)
    40          25          0,50     =PERCENTRANK($A1:$A4, B4)`

Answer (score 0):

This could serve as an approximate, not foolproof numerical solution with column being passed as a name:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[PERCENTRANK_column](
    @colname nvarchar(50) 
)
RETURNS @resultingtable TABLE(
    RowID int,
    PercentRank float
)
AS
BEGIN


;WITH true_CDF AS (
    SELECT 

        PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY 
            CASE @colname
            WHEN 'X'    THEN X 
            WHEN 'Y'    THEN Y
            ELSE NULL
            END
        ASC) as PercentRank
        ,
        CASE @colname
            WHEN 'X'    THEN X 
            WHEN 'Y'    THEN Y
            ELSE NULL
        END AS selected_col
    FROM dbo.MainTable
)
, selectColumn AS (
    SELECT 
    m.RowID
    ,CASE @colname
            WHEN 'X'    THEN to_score_X 
            WHEN 'Y'    THEN to_score_Y
            ELSE NULL
      END as to_score
      FROM dbo.MainTable m 
)
, added_Mins AS (
    SELECT
          B.RowID
        , ABS(B.to_score - A.selected_col) as diff
        , MIN(ABS(B.to_score - A.selected_col)) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) as lowest_difference
        , A.PercentRank
    FROM selectColumn B
    CROSS JOIN true_CDF A
)
INSERT INTO @resultingtable
SELECT
    RowID, PercentRank
FROM added_Mins
WHERE lowest_difference = diff

RETURN

END
```